# How to proceed when user is(was) adding 'callouts' to their questions targeting downvoters

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

Well, I kind of feel I'm right, here, but I want to make sure before I proceed any further; I've come upon a user who experienced downvotes, and thinks they're apparently being targeted by a single individual... and thus, left a 'message' calling out this person on many of their past questions.  Of course, they're doing it on their future questions too.

I removed this message on two of their questions; the one that I found while browsing, and another while checking their history for any signs of being serially downvoted.  To be clear, I didn't really.. dig deep, but it doesn't appear they were.

To the questions; I feel that those messages have no place in a question; am I right to remove them?  Especially when they're appearing in such frequency?

How should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, remove them, and if it gets put back in, flag for moderator and clearly explain what is going on.

Comment: From my point of view he is just *asking* for more downvotes with that comments...

Comment: Kudos for not calling out the particular user here and starting a Meta witch hunt. *(puts away torch and pitchfork)*

Comment: @KevinB: Comments are for requesting clarification and berating people, not writing answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes; you are absolutely right. Such messages are noise. Especially disruptive noise, in fact.

If there's more than a couple - or if even a single one gets rolled back after - the next step should be to flag one of their posts with the "Other" reason, and explain what they are doing.